# loop for class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-selectors

How do I create loop for class between 1 to 6 ?

HTML:

```
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
```

code:

```
var qtt=10;   
for (var i =1;i<8;i++){
//document.getElementById("s"+i+"_0").value=qtt
$(".pointer:eq('i')")[0].click();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems you haven't read the comment on your previous question: "Please elaborate your problem...! "

Comment: @Vohuman want loop for this `$(".pointer:eq(1)")[0].click();`

Comment: @jhonde What do you want to do in loop?

Comment: @Mohammad loop for next class

Comment: @jhonde What is meaning of `loop for next class`? Do you want to add click handler to elements? Please explain exactly

Comment: @Mohammad  `var qtt=10;   
    for (var i =1;i<8;i++){
    //document.getElementById("s"+i+"_0").value=qtt
    $(".pointer:eq('i')")[0].click();
    }`

Comment: @jhonde Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qo2pf5rd/) your purpose?

Comment: @Mohammad yes right but not once at all i want one by one or possible to remove that class which one is clicked ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not force open a popup. Even simulating a click on an element will not work. Can you imagine the infinite publicity popups we would have?

If your original goal was to provide information in a "popup" style way. Try looking into [modals](http://jquerymodal.com) or [bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com).